# changing the field of specialisation in PhD

Tags: phd, changing-fields

I have a masters in management studies with a specialisation in Marketing. Can I now do a PhD in Psychology? What would be required to become eligible in India? Esp. Mumbai? What are my options?

Comment: You should ask the universities where you want to do phd. If there is a good interdisciplinary topic/project, this mitht be possible.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a masters in management studies with a specialisation in Marketing. Can I now do a PhD in Psychology?

It sounds unlikely without taking at least some more relevant courses, but I would recommend to check the websites of Mumbai Universities' Psychology institutes, pick out fields of research that sound interesting to you, and send a brief, concise e-mail to the respective group leaders where you state your education and interest.